# PostgreSQL 9.4 - Elements of jsonb array to ts_vector in

Tags: json, postgresql, full-text-search, tsvector, nosql

I'm currently playing around with a NOSQL database in PostgreSQL. It contains 3 tables with id, data (jsonb) and tsv (tsvector) fields.

I'm having some difficulties creating the tsvector from the data field. With jsonb objects I don't have any problems:

For something like this:

```
    {"genres":{"genre": "Electronic"}, 
    "labels": {"label": {"@name": "Turbo", "@catno": "HEMI-06PU"}}, 
    "styles": {"style": ["House", "Techno", "Tech House"]}}
```

I used:

```
UPDATE rel SET tsv = setweight(to_tsvector(coalesce(data->>'genre','')),'B') || 
    setweight(to_tsvector(coalesce(data->'labels'->'label'->>'@name','')),'C') || 
    setweight(to_tsvector(coalesce(data->'styles'->>'style','')),'D');
```

But now I also have nested structures like this one:

```
    "tracklist": {"track": [
     {"title": "Untitled", 
      "artists": {"artist": {"id": "676", "anv": null, "join": ",", "name": "Peter Benisch", "role": null, "tracks": null}}, 
      "duration": "5:42", 
      "position": "1"}, 
     {"title": "Good Morning", 
      "artists": {"artist": {"id": "166", "anv": null, "join": ",", "name": "Fred Everything", "role": null, "tracks": null}}, 
      "duration": "4:10", 
      "position": "2"}]
```

I'm trying to get every title of all the tracks in the "track"-array into my tsvector. The number of tracks may differ throughout the table.

I've tried using

```
    (jsonb_array_elements(data->'tracklist'->'track'))->>'title'
```

which gave me one title per row.

Can anyone help with getting these rows as input for the to_tsvector() function? Or is there a different solution to this?

Comment: maybe this would help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31699645/expand-multiple-rows-result-of-jsonb-array-elements-to-tsvector-inside-a-pl-pg

Answer (score 0):

maybe can help you, my table have prop as jsonb data

```
{"title":"title 1","description":"description bla","tags":["tag1","tag2"]}
```

when i get the tags:

```
SELECT prop->'tags' from test;
```

this return a object like this

```
{"tags":["tag1","tag2"]}
```

in this case i use 'tags'->'tags' and get the array of elements

```
SELECT prop->'tags'->'tags' from test;
```

this return array:

```
["tag1","tags2"]
```

get elements on the array with this function jsonb_array_elements_text() and use a WITH clause for encapsulate a result and return like rows

```
WITH r AS
(Select jsonb_array_elements_text(prop->'tags'->'tags') AS tags
FROM test)
SELECT to_tsvector('simple',string_agg(tags,' ')) AS ts_vector FROM r;
```

is recomendable when fields like tags, users or other fields are 'simple' because this fields not have 'stop words'