# Expand multiple rows result of `jsonb_array_elements` to tsvector inside a PL/pgSQL procedure

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, tsvector

overflowers,

I have a JSON array **items** like this (PostgreSQL 9.4):

```
[{name: "foo"},
 {name: "bar"},
 {name: "baz"}]
```

What I want is to concatenate all item's **name** into a **tsvector**-typed column so that I can create index on that column.

And if I run:

```
SELECT to_tsvector(array_to_string(array(SELECT jsonb_array_elements(items)->>'name' FROM store), ','))
```

I can get an expected result: `'foo': 1 'bar': 2 'baz': 3`

But I got stuck at something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_tsv()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    NEW.tsv = to_tsvector(jsonb_array_elements(NEW.items)->>'name');
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ language 'plpgsql';
```

The `to_tsvector` complains about multiple rows.

A [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7671d/3) is attached.

Any help will be extremely appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would you try like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_tsv()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    NEW.tsv = to_tsvector(array_to_string(array( select json_array_elements(NEW.items)->>'name' ),' '));
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ language 'plpgsql';
```